# No Internet on router with pfSense

Tags: firewall, router, internet, pfsense, dsl

Sorry in advance if a similar question has already been posted.

I am with Sky for broadband and have a router providing DSL connectivity. I have a cheap 64 bit desktop PC running pFsense as a firewall. The problem I am experiencing is that, even though I have configured my WAN interface with a static IP address and unchecked the boxes that relate to blocking private IP ranges so that pFsense doesn't block traffic coming in from my router, I still can't connect to the internet.

I know the Ethernet card I am using is supported because my router can see my firewall but it is as if, when I am connected to the new LAN behind the firewall, I cannot see the default gateway and Windows reports no internet connectivity.

I do not know what I am doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction or advise me of what I need to do?

Comment: It seems, your question is considered offtopic here. I suggest to re-ask this on http://superuser.com, where it probably won't be so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you login to the PFsense box, can you use the commandline / ping utility to ping either the sky router, or the internet at large?

The PFsense box should likely have the **WAN setup as DHCP**, not static as it'll get the IP it should be using from the Sky Router (which will provide it via DHCP).

And then you'll likely want the internal IP of the PFsense box to be static and use this as the gateway for your 'local' clients, or just setup DHCP server on the PFsense box and let it take care of the routing and gateway.

Comment: When I logon to the box via SSH and do a ping, it just appears to hang.

Comment: Sounds like the static IP setup on the WAN is incorrect then, either set it correctly (the gateway will likely be the IP of the Sky router, other settings I'd be completely guessing) or just set the pfsense box to connect using dhcp.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that, when I had the WAN interface set to static, I had the WAN Upstream gateway set to the IP of my router when it might have wanted to be in my LAN Uplink gateway. I have set it back them both to DHCP but I don't think it is letting me change it

Comment: OK, for whatever reason, my router isn't giving pFsense an IP address via DHCP

Comment: Can you tempoarly connect a normal PC to it(The sky router), to see if that works? If it's not giving out IP's, something more is wrong.

Has it worked before? Has it been rebooted?

Comment: Yeah, I have three devices connected currently, but I will check anyway

Comment: I guess I could try forcing rn0 to get a DHCP address using ifconfig

Comment: OK, swapped the network interfaces over and now it connects to the internet but I can't access it LAN side